# Is there com.sun.faces.enableAgressiveSessionDirtying for view scope?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, replication, view-scope

The following config parameter in `web.xml` causes the `@SessionScoped` managed beans to replicate  across a cluster:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableAgressiveSessionDirtying</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Is there some parameter like `enableAgressiveViewDirtying`? According to the [comments here](/questions/6008090/how-to-use-jsf2-0-view-scope-in-cluster-environment) it is not possible to replicate `@ViewScoped` state across a cluster. Is this true? I am using Weblogic 10.3.6 with Mojarra 2.1.2. Could it be implementation-specific? If I switched to CDI, would there be a chance it would work better?

[This answer](/questions/12094077/jsf-session-fail-over-and-partial-state-saving?newreg=623065f7a5a4458aafd51f47228b6ab4) claims a listener can do it. However, I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Mojarra bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20279. Currently `@ViewScoped` is not replicated in a cluster.